# Using varchar(8000) column value in HashByte md5 function

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a hash using all the row values in SQL. In that table one of the column length is varchar(8000).I put a hashbyte function like below -

```
Hashbyte('MD5',column1+column2+....) -- column1 having varchar(8000) length and it contains string of length 8000.
```

Then it gives me same hashbyte where the rows having same value in column1 even if other columns contains different data

Then I converted column1 to varchar(max) in hashbyte function, I got different hashbyte for each row.

```
Hashbyte('MD5',convert(varchar(max),column1)+column2+....)
```

Why the hashbyte('MD5'...) wont take all column values?

If you want to try one more example of having varchar(8000) column issue-
try to calculate the length

create a table having column with varchar(8000) and calculate length of all column values. It will give you 8000 only. Next convert the varchar(8000) to varchar(max) it will give you correct result.

```
len(column1+column2...) --> 8000
len(convert(varchar(max),column1)+column2...) --> actual length
```

adding any string with varchar(8000) is such an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're under the misconception that a `varchar(8000)` concatenated to a `varchar(8000)` (or even any other length <= 8000) results in a `varchar(MAX)`. This is not true. To get a `MAX` length you **must** define at least one of the values in the expression as a `MAX`.

This is confirmed in the remarks in [+ (String Concatenation) (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks):

> #### Remarks
>
> ...
>
> If the result of the concatenation of strings exceeds the limit of 8,000 bytes, the result is truncated. However, if at least one of the strings concatenated is a large value type, truncation does not occur.

As a result you need to convert one of the values first to `MAX` and then the rest would implicitly be cast to a `MAX` as well. If you don't explicitly convert (at least) one of the expressions, then the value will be truncated, as the documentation states.

Obviously this applies to `nvarchar` as well, where truncation occurs at 4,000 characters (which is still 8,000 bytes).